# Knockout Dropdown list Initial Value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to setup the initial value of the dropdown list on button click event. But its not selecting the item.

```js
var viewModel = function () {
    this.itemsSingle = ko.observableArray([
       { id: 1, name: "Apple" }, 
       { id: 2, name: "Orange"},
       { id: 3, name: "Banana"}
   ]);
   this.selected = ko.observableArray();
   this.selectedSingle = ko.observable();
    this.Change = function(){        
        this.selectedSingle({ id: 3, name: "Banana"});
    };
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[JsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/balain/47Lpd42w/2/)

Comment: Hi Still I have problem in selecting the item. I have posted the code in jsfiddle [link](jsfiddle.net/balain/47Lpd42w/4). Thank you for your help. –  balaG 2 mins ago    edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @dotnetom mentioned, you also have a scope problem with `this` in your click handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/47Lpd42w/6/

```
this.Change = function(){        
    this.selectedSingle({ id: 3, name: "Banana"});
};
```

The inner `this` is not what you think it is. If you look at the attached jsfiddle, you'll see I combined what @dotnetom did, plus I used a `self` object to get your closure working properly.

Comment: if you use optionsCaption: 'Choose a fruit' in the binding then this solution is not working. can you check this [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/balain/47Lpd42w/4)

Comment: you're still using `this` incorrectly. Also, you're trying to display `selectedSingle().name` when `selectedSingle` hasn't been set. I added a null check to your code. see http://jsfiddle.net/47Lpd42w/11/

Comment: Thank you [link] (http:// jsfiddle.net/47Lpd42w/11) works. yes dperry i missed the null check.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
this.selectedSingle({ id: 3, name: "Banana"});
```

creates a new object which is not the same as is in the list. If you want to set a value you need to provide the same object that you have in your collection. You can use such code to set the value to `Banana`:

```
this.selectedSingle(this.itemsSingle()[2]);
```

Comment: Hi Still I have problem in selecting the item. I have posted the code in jsfiddle [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/balain/47Lpd42w/4/). Thank you for your help.